# Inequality with second time derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading Yajima's paper "On smoothing property of Schroedinger propagators".
At page 30 there is the following inequality:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vert x(t)\vert^2\geq\frac{\vert\eta\vert^2}{100}\,.$$
From this it follows that
$$\vert x(t)\vert^2\geq(200)^{-1}\vert\eta\vert^2(t-\sigma)^2+\vert x(\sigma)\vert^2\,,$$
for some $s-T\leq\sigma\leq s+T$.
Now, in order to get the second inequality, one integrates the first one. By doing this, should be a term missing in the second inequality? Precisely, in the right handside it should appear the term
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vert x(t)\vert^2\bigg|_{t=\sigma}(t-\sigma)\,.$$
Why this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the paper in front of me, but from your description you have that $\sigma$ is not arbitrary, but a chosen point in the interval $[s-T, s+T]$. Therefore the only interpretation is that $\sigma$ is chosen precisely so that $\frac{d}{dt} |x(t)|^2 |_{t=\sigma} = 0$.

Presumably there is another argument which guarantees that such a $\sigma$ exists in your interval. But I can't tell you more without looking at the paper. (Incidentally, if you are asking a question about a specific paper, please include a DOI or at least full citation information, not just author name and title.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; I tought to the same argument you said, but I don't see the reason why this point shoul exist.

Comment: I found the paper. The author gives a lower bound on $|\eta|$ using constants that are related to the choice of $T$ (pg 29), and also proves an _upper_ bound on $|x|$ (pg 30). If you have an upper bound on a convex function, a lower bound on the length of its domain, and a lower bound on its second derivative, you have enough ingredients to in principle guarantee the existence of a turning point. (Note also that $|x| > 0$ by definition.)